# sql-group by query

Tags: sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am doing my SQL project on this days and I need help.

I have table that called "players" and another table that called "statistics".
I Want to get the best player for each role.
I have wrought this query and I got only the role and the grade.
I want to get the first_name and last_name of this players.

What should I add to this query that I would get it

```
select   role, max(grade) 
from     players 
join     statistics 
on       players.player_id=statistics.player_id 
group by role
```

Comment: can you add your table schema?

Comment: Hi Amit, welcome to SO! Please consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask. You can add the columns to your select something like this: select first_name, last_name, role from players;

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: even this question was answered,consider looking at this link,to know more on how to ask a perfect question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: also please tag the DBMS you are using like SQLServer/Oracle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a common table expression and a window function:

```
WITH Ranks AS (
    SELECT first_name, last_name, role, grade, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY role ORDER BY grade DESC) AS rank
    FROM players
        join statistics on(
            players.player_id = statistics.player_id
        )
)
SELECT first_name, last_name, role, grade
FROM Ranks
WHERE rank = 1
```

It's necessary to do this because if you simply add `first_name` and `last_name` to the `SELECT` clause, you'll get an error, and if you add them to your `GROUP BY` clause too, you'll get one row per player, which isn't what you want.

---

### Explanatory edit

#### Common table expression

The `WITH Ranks AS ( /*query*/ )` bit is like a subquery; it's a query whose results are used in the main query, which comes afterwards. Here we're taking all players, and their rank within their role.

You can read more about common table expressions (CTEs) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

#### Windowing function

The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY role ORDER BY grade DESC)` bit defines a new column to the query. It says:

*Take the result set, and split it into partitions that have the same `role` value. Then order by the value of `grade`, descending. Finally, assign a row number within each partition, with the ordering already established.*

You can read more about window functions [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1).

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about this query?  What it means "WITH Rans As", "OVER (PARTITION BY role ORDER BY grade DESC) AS rank"

Comment: I've added an explanation of those parts. Hope they make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to add to the select portion of your query?

```
select
    first_name, -- Column name guessed as you haven't shared your table structure with us
    last_name,
    role,
    max(grade)
from
    players
    join statistics on(
        players.player_id = statistics.player_id
    )
group by
    first_name,
    last_name,
    role
```

Comment: think you may want to add `first_name`, and `last_name` to your  `group by` clause, otherwise you may get an error...

Comment: This is an invalid `group by` usage